# ASP Master.FindControl object reference not set to an instance

Tags: asp.net

this is where where the error is happening, any thoughts?  I'm sure it's something simple.

```
Control masterC = Master.FindControl("ContactPlaceHolder_Header");
```

This is defined in `Website.master.cs` which is not a nested master page (it doesn't have a master page of its own).

Comment: Where does this line of code live? If in a page, does it have a master page associated to it?

Comment: @Oded it lives in the Website.master.cs in behind code

Comment: And does this master page have a master page associated with it (yes, you can nest master pages, for those who didn't know)?

Comment: No there is no nested master pages

Comment: @Oded this is simple 1 master page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Master` property of a master page refers to *its* master page.

Since you don't have one for the master page on which this code is defined, `Master` is `null`, explaining the exception.

Just change your code to:

```
Control masterC = FindControl("ContactPlaceHolder_Header");
```

And all will be right in the world (or at least the place this master page takes in it).